# get the checksum of a file and update another file with this checksum in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a file `test_proc.init` in a particular directory. And I have one more file `desc.cmd` in the same directory which has below content:

```
set_poc 204 6
send_data_file goldy_proc.init 4e8ee8946f7a89d2eb501a752c5e3ee6ea266e5b
set_poc 204 7
send_data_file goldy_proc.init 4e8ee8946f7a89d2eb501a752c5e3ee6ea266e5b
set_poc 204 8
send_data_file goldy_proc.init 4e8ee8946f7a89d2eb501a752c5e3ee6ea266e5b
set_poc 204 9
send_data_file goldy_proc.init 4e8ee8946f7a89d2eb501a752c5e3ee6ea266e5b
```

Below is what I want to do:

- I want to get the `sha1sum` of `test_proc.init` file: `sha1sum test_proc.init`.
- And whatever is the output from that `sha1sum` command, I want to copy that checksum and update the `desc.cmd` file.

So if new checksum is `e32313118e53b60140d2024dfa7578c3fd89b346` the my `desc.cmd` file will be like this:

```
set_poc 204 6
send_data_file goldy_proc.init e32313118e53b60140d2024dfa7578c3fd89b346
set_poc 204 7
send_data_file goldy_proc.init e32313118e53b60140d2024dfa7578c3fd89b346
set_poc 204 8
send_data_file goldy_proc.init e32313118e53b60140d2024dfa7578c3fd89b346
set_poc 204 9
send_data_file goldy_proc.init e32313118e53b60140d2024dfa7578c3fd89b346
```

Is this possible to do in ansible? I am not sure on how can I paste the checksum and update the file.

```
- name: Get sha1sum of file
  stat:
    path: /data/test_proc.init
    checksum_algorithm: sha1sum
    get_checksum: yes
  register: shell_stat
```

Answer (score 4):

The output of the `stat` command should already contain the sha of the file:

```
- name: Get sha1sum of file
  stat:
    path: /data/test_proc.init
    checksum_algorithm: sha1sum
    get_checksum: yes
  register: sha
```

It can than be used with a module like `lineinfile` or `blockinfile` to update the `desc.cmd` file like this:

```
- name: insert sha
  lineinfile:
    path: /data/desc.cmd
    line: "{{ sha.stat.checksum }}"
```

Comment: thanks for explanation but my `desc.cmd` file is little bit different. Somehow I need to replace previous checksum with new checksum so I need to do something to replace the previous one with new one. basically my command should know where to replace with new one?

Comment: [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#parameters) module comes with a `regexp` parameter to identify the line which should be replaced.

Comment: Aah I see. Can you tell me how can I use to work in my case?

Comment: you still around?